# How to push value in for loop to the mongo document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to store every day of the year in the Mongo Database.

I'm not quite sure how to do this. I've been trying to use $push method and .update method. They both seems to be bad in this case.

My controller:

```
exports.reflux = (req, res) => {
    const newDay = new Calendar();

    for(let i=3; i<367; i++) {
        newDay({$push: {day: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, i), offWork: true, description: ' '}});

    }
    // for(let i=3; i<367; i++){
    //
    //     {$push: {newDay.day = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, i);}}
    //     newDay.day =
    //     newDay.offWork = true;
    //     newDay.description = '';
    // }

    newDay.save();

};
```

I expect the output to be collection of ducuments for every single day of the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

> [insertMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany)

First, create an array of objects (all your days) then do insert

```
let days = [];
for(let i=3; i<367; i++) {
    days.push({day: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, i), offWork: true, description: ' '});
}

newDay.insertMany(days, function(err) {

});
```

Comment: Thats a good point, however it results in insertMany is not a function.

Comment: use the latest version  of mongoose https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

Comment: Ahh ye i figured out the problem. Instead of newDay.insertMany i should use Calendar.insertMany.

Comment: Glad you found it. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Done.

```
exports.reflux = (req, res) => {
    for(let i=3; i<367; i++) {
        const newDay = new Calendar();
        newDay.day = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, i);
        newDay.offWork = true;
        newDay.description = '';

        newDay.save(err => {
            if(err) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: This will insert on 367 times and your program will be slow. whenever you want to insert more data use `insertMany` this will insert only one time as batch